# Coded UI Test DateTime issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I use coded UI test and I have a problem. I want to type a date in edittext, but it gives an error message, where is the problem,thanks.

```
public void TheDate()
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    HtmlEdit uITxtDateEdit = this.UIEWindowWindow8.UIDemoSiteDocument.UITxtDateEdit;
    #endregion

    uITxtDateEdit.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");            
}
```

> Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "16.08.2013"' on the control.
>
> Additional Details:
>
> TechnologyName:  'Web'
>   ControlType:  'Edit'
>   TagName:  'INPUT'
>   Id:  'ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_wpm1_gwpc1_c1_txtDepartureDate_txtDate'
>   Name:  'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$wpm1$gwpc1$c1$txtDepartureDate_txtDate'

Comment: You can try to use the Type-Function instead of setting the text-properts

Answer (score 0):

uITxtDateEdit.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

You are trying to insert date in other format. either use dd/mm/yyyy or modify the format to dd.mm.yyyy. Secondly you have mention MM (Capital) which is used for minutes. Try this hope it resolve your issues.